# what are other data structures that support random access besides array?

Tags: arrays, data-structures, random-access

I'm trying to think if there is any other data structure that support random access (i.e: constant time complexity)
It looks to me like only array is built this way.

Note: you can't build a data structure on top of array

Comment: Can this include data structures built on top of arrays? Most will be built using an array, for example a hash table

Comment: No, you cannot built on top of array - i have edited ;)

Comment: Does "support" mean O(1) time complexity for random access? I can make a binary tree permit random access but it won't be O(1)

Answer (score 2):

Hash tables also allow random access given a key. So contrary to arrays they are key-based, not index-based, but still allow for a O(1) access to a given element.

Comment: Yes but they are usually implemented using an array for the hashed keys

Comment: add "circular buffer" to the "built using arrays, with O(1) random access" list

Comment: Isn't the key simply an array index using the hash and a modulo?

Answer (score 1):

In the end it depends on what you mean with "Array". I'll tell you that the RAM is a big array of bytes (technically a big array of bytes plus some overloaded methods to read them in blocks of 1, 2, (nearly always)4 and (sometimes)8 bytes that not always work well (or not work full stop) if you try to read starting from a byte "unaligned" with that number). So everything is built on top of an Array.

If by "Array" you only mean "the structure the language I'm using calls Array and all the structures of that language based on that array", then I could simply (in C code) `malloc` a slab of memory and use it in a manner similar to an array (and perhaps build on top of it an Hash table). The key word is "similar".

Given enough Virtual Address space you could use `VirtualAlloc` (under Windows, `mmap` under linux) to emulate an Hash Table using the MMU of your computer. It would be quite expensive and useless :-) And I would still consider it to be an Array by another name (a "sparse" Array).

Answer (score 0):

I can think of lists and dictionaries.
As dictionaries are key-value pairs, they are "more" random-access friendly.